# How to overload both unary and binary minus operators in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In C++, how are the operator overloading functions distinguished for the unary and binary minus operators?

I am trying to overload both with the following code:

```
Vector Vector::operator-(){
  return Vector(-x,-y,-z);
}

Vector Vector::operator-(const Vector& v){
  return this* + (-v);
}
```

But this spews a lot of errors:

```
vector.cpp: In member function ‘Vector Vector::operator-(const Vector&)’:
vector.cpp:88:20: error: passing ‘const Vector’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘Vector Vector::operator-()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   return this* + (-v);
                    ^
vector.cpp:88:16: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand type is ‘Vector’)
   return this* + (-v);
                ^
vector.cpp:88:16: note: candidates are:
vector.cpp:70:8: note: Vector Vector::operator+(const Vector&)
 Vector Vector::operator+(const Vector& v){
        ^
...
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Implement as a free function, not a member function. Or (if you insist on implementing as a member function) mark it as a `const` member function, i.e. `Vector Vector::operator-(const Vector&) const;` and Vector Vector::operator-() const;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.`v` is passed by reference to const, it can't be called with non-const member function. Since `operator-` and `operator+` (both unary and binary version) doesn't modify members of class, you should make them const member functions.

```
Vector Vector::operator-() const {
  return Vector(-x,-y,-z);
}
```

2.Change

```
return this* + (-v);
```

to

```
return *this + (-v);
```

Comment: @brandbest1 It's just a syntax error. `this* + (-v);` will call unary `operator-` on `v`, and call unary `operator+` on the returned value, then failed since you only define a binary `operator+`. `*this + (-v)` will call unary `operator-` on `v`, and `*this` will dereference `this` and then call binary `operator+` with them.